# C# Telegram Bot Inline Mode Send Button to user

Tags: c#, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to create an inline bot with: [Telegram.Bot](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot)

I have added a method to the `OnInlineQuery` event. It gets called, But now I want to send a button back to the chat, which should be displayed above the keyboard. How do I accomplish this?

This is what I have so far:

```cs
BotClient.OnInlineQuery += BotOnInlineQuery;

protected async override void BotOnInlineQuery(object sender, InlineQueryEventArgs inlineQueryEventArgs)
{
    // Log info
    Log.Info("Inline called " + inlineQueryEventArgs.InlineQuery.From.FirstName);

    InlineQueryResult[] results =
    {
        new InlineQueryResultVenue()
    };


    await BotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(inlineQueryEventArgs.InlineQuery.Id, "test");
    
    // Answer with results
    await BotClient.AnswerInlineQueryAsync(
                    inlineQueryEventArgs.InlineQuery.Id,
                    results,
                    isPersonal: true,
                    cacheTime: 0);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to send message with button to inline chat?

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code:

1. You can't use `SendTextMessageAsync` with `InlineQuery.Id`
2. There is no constructor for `InlineQueryResultVenue` with no parameters
3. You can't override `OnInlineQuery` because it's not a method, It's an event!

---

#### Answer

To use Buttons with inline message use `ReplyMarkup` property with `InlineKeyboardMarkup` in `InlineQueryResultBase`.

And use chat links t.me,
if I have username *@BotFather* use link: https://t.me/BotFather

So use `InlineKeyboardButton.WithUrl("Go to chat", "https://t.me/my_chat_username")` with your chat link.

Use this code:

```cs
private async void BotClient_OnInlineQuery(object sender, InlineQueryEventArgs e)
{
    // Some variables
    string link = "https://t.me/chat_username";
    // Your Button that you want
    InlineKeyboardButton button = InlineKeyboardButton.WithUrl("Go to chat", link);

    // Inline Results
    InlineQueryResultBase[] results = new[]  
    {
        new InlineQueryResultVenue(e.InlineQuery.Id, 30, 30, "Venue title", "address")
        //TODO: Add here any of InlineQueryResultVenue properties.
        {
            // HERE IS WHAT DO YOU WANT:
            // Keyboard:
            ReplyMarkup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(button);
        }
    }
    
    // Answer with results:
    await BotClient.AnswerInlineQueryAsync(e.InlineQuery.Id,
                                           results,
                                           isPersonal: true
                                           cacheTime: 0);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to simply send text message, not venue?